# regex pattern matching in HTML5 is not working properly

Tags: regex, html, forms

I have an input text box in my HTML form which looks for a regex pattern as shown below.
I am looking for anything to be entered other than white spaces or blank. I tried all the following below and none of them is allowing me to enter any normal text such as "hello world" and "helloworld" in it.Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks

```
<input name="item" type="text" size="25" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="^\S$" title="Enter something valid"/>

<input name="item" type="text" size="25" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="^[^\s]*$" title="Enter something valid"/>

<input name="item" type="text" size="25" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="^[\S]*$" title="Enter something valid"/>
```

EDIT:

after removing the anchor, this works for "helloworld" but not for "hello world". So I think it has to do with regex pattern.

```
<input name="item" type="text" size="25" autofocus="autofocus" pattern="[^\s]*" title="Enter something valid"/>
```

Comment: Perhaps the pattern attribute doesn't need delimiters?

Comment: I edited the code above, I did not have delimiters when I tested. but still no luck

Comment: It would be easier if you just add the `required` attribute. That will prevent empty value submissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\s]*` will match against anything that contains no spaces, so a space in the words will not match.

You probably want something like `.*[^\s].*` to match a string with at least one non-space character.

The `required` attribute is probably the best way to guard against blanks (or `^$` should work).